# apache rewrite rule for URL

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My java application is deployed on tomcat and i am using rewrite rule from apache to access the application using apache.
My application name is  my.war deployed on tomcat/webapps/my/

i am using following rewrite rule in httpd.conf

```
    RewriteEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    RewriteRule ^/$  \
    http://localhost:8082/my [P]

    RewriteRule ^/(my/.*)$  \
    http://localhost:8082/$1 [P,R,L]
```

when i open www.mydomain.com/  it  changed the url to www.mydomain.com/my/
i don't want this , i want the url be www.mydomain.com/ and it should open the landing page of my application.

Answer (score 0):

You should use mod_proxy's `ProxyPass` instead:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8082/my/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the application as your "ROOT" application on tomcat. Tomcat will automatically make that .war the base URL when you land on tomcat. To do this, just rename your "my.war" to "ROOT.war" and redeploy it.

Note, on some Tomcat instances, there will be a pre-installed default "ROOT" application for managing some Tomcat settings and apps via a web UI. Deploying your own ROOT.war will naturally replace this utility.